# How do linear guides work?

Tags: linear-motion

I am new to the office and I wanted to ask about linear guides like shown in the picture:[image]

(source: https://www.nskeurope.de/de/linear-motion-control/products/linear-guides.html)

Are the carriages able to move on the bar if you put them on there? And is there a way to keep them fixed in one position? How do you usually attach something to the slider? And are there maybe any ressources where you can look how these linear guides are used for example? Because I was looking online but I did not find any typical uses of them. Thanks for a response!

Comment: You find them in everywhere in industrial equipment. Dovetails and ball/roller bearings. You can see them in your image. https://www.mcmaster.com/linear-rails/

Comment: The pictures items restrict motion to one degree of freedom.  Most of what you seem to be asking about is available on the internet.  Do a video search for "how to install linear guide rail". Throw in nsk also and you get even more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do linear guides work?

https://www.anaheimautomation.com/manuals/forms/linear-guide.php

Linear guides serve three purposes;

1. reduce lateral/radial motion to some minimum slack

   - a wide variety of options from many axial bearings for maximum radial support to a simple rotary axel bearing with internal balls for lower cost just as in drawer slides or sleeve bearing for the lowest cost.
2. reduce axial friction to some minimum requirement

   - depends on material wear, contaminants, and lubricants
3. support a moving object with mounting holes on a block.

   - threaded mounting holes exist often metric.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Are the carriages able to move on the bar if you put them on there?

The slider(carriage) moves along the rail (bar) in 1 axis.

> And is there a way to keep them fixed in one position?

No, common linear rails do not include a brake or anything like that. Usually these will be paired with some kind of actuator like a ball screw.

> How do you usually attach something to the slider?

Every slider is different but they will likely have mounting holes. You would therefore attach things to them with bolts.

> And are there maybe any ressources where you can look how these linear guides are used for example?

Look at CNC machines, 3d printers, and laser cutters. Almost all of them use linear guides of some kind.